# `render="@all"` (no page reload) vs `update="@all"` (page reloaded)

Tags: ajax, forms, primefaces, jsf-2, facelets

I noticed that if I use

```
<f:ajax .... execute="@form" render="@all" />
```

my page gets reloaded, whereas using

```
<p:ajax .... process="@form" update="@all" /> // note the "p"
```

it doesn't.

**UPDATE**

Header part of my layout, where this form is located.

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">


    <header>
        <div style="padding: 5px 0; text-align: right">

            <h:form id="frmSelectLang">
                <h:selectOneMenu id="selectLang" value="#{userBean.locale}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.availableLangs}" />
                    <!--f:ajax execute="@form" render="@all"/-->
                    <p:ajax process="@form" update="@all" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </h:form>

        </div>
    </header>

</ui:composition>
```

While I may prefer the former (commented out) approach (due to sticking with Facelets), page reload with the latter solves this issue I'm having with the former.

Namely, if I switch the language and then add something through another form in the main part of the page (the above code is part of another form in the header - lang switcher), then the first click isn't being recognised. The same is true for deleting (there's the ajax-driven `delete` button next to the item).

**UPDATE 2**

This is the form I submit to add a City (Grad), and when added, there's a delete button next to each input:

```
<h:form id="frmGrad">
    <h:inputText id="naziv" label="Naziv grada" size="40" required="true" requiredMessage="Polje ne smije biti prazno!" value="#{gradManager.naziv}" />
    <h:commandButton id="submit" action="#{gradManager.kreiraj()}" value="#{btnlabels['btnSubmit']}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":frmDelete:spisak :foobar"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

<hr />

<h:form id="frmDelete">
    <h:dataTable id="spisak" value="#{gradManager.gradovi}" var="grad">
        <h:column>
            <h:commandButton id="submit" action="#{gradManager.obrisi(grad.id)}" value="Obriši">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="frmDelete:spisak foobar" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>#{grad.naziv}</h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Is there a convenient way to fix this? I'd like to know the underlaying cause, despite the fact I may end up using the working approach.

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Something else is going on. Perhaps you're actually trying to use `<f:ajax>` inside a `<p:xxx>` component instead of a `<h:xxx>` component?

Comment: Isn't this the part where: "Update `@all` is such a bad idea PrimeFaces does not implement it by design."? I'm not up to date if it is about PF (but I remember that @BalusC made some pull requests about fixing `@all` not working in (part of?) PF)

Comment: @BalusC The form the above code  belongs to contains <f:selectOneMenu>

Comment: Wait, let's exclude an ambiguity: what exactly do you mean with "page reload"? I interpreted it as a full page refresh as result of a synchronous GET request because of f:ajax not functioning at all. Is this true? If you're unsure, please confirm by inspecting HTTP traffic monitor.

Comment: @BalusC The reload happens when I simply change a language in the dropdown list, Ajax driven

Comment: So you've an `onchange="submit()"` there? A [mcve] would be more helpful.

Comment: @BalusC Please see my update there. There's no `onchange()` but the form submits anyway when I select a different option. Regarding the Minimal, Complete, .... example, I guess it would be difficult for me as a beginner in Java to put together, especially because the DB operations are involved.